# How can i change the Source Code of my Corda Node

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, corda

I want to change the Source Code of my Corda Node. In the build.gradle the following 3 lines import the Corda-Dependencies:

```
cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-core:$corda_release_version"
cordaRuntime "$corda_release_group:corda-node-api:$corda_release_version"
cordaRuntime "$corda_release_group:corda:$corda_release_version"
```

Now i have forked the Corda project and want to change the way they get imported by gradle by adding the local corda project to my own cordapp in the settings.gradle with:

```
includeBuild '../corda'
```

And then changing the dependencies in my build.gradle to

```
cordaCompile project(":core")
cordaRuntime project(":node-api")
cordaRuntime project(":corda")
```

However when i run the gradle script the following Error returns

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':corda-project'.
>
> > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.r3.testing.distributed-testing']
> > Could not create an instance of type com.r3.testing.DistributedTestingExtension.
> > > org.gradle.api.model.ObjectFactory.domainObjectContainer(Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/gradle/api/NamedDomainObjectFactory;)Lorg/gradle/api/NamedDomainObjectContainer;

Since the forked project builds fine on his own but throws an Error when used by my project i dont know how to fix this. If anybody knows how i can import the forked project or has experience on how to customize corda source code, that would help me out alot.

Comment: To anyone wondering. I managed to deploy a Corda Node with my custom Source Code by running the ./gradlew assemble command in the forked corda project. Next i replaced my own projects corda.jar with the corda/node/capsule/build/libs/corda.XXX-SNAPSHOT.jar that resulted from the gradle command

Answer (score 0):

Pasting the answer from Oalfreda's comments -

I managed to deploy a Corda Node with my custom Source Code by running the ./gradlew assemble command in the forked corda project. Next i replaced my own projects corda.jar with the corda/node/capsule/build/libs/corda.XXX-SNAPSHOT.jar that resulted from the gradle command.